# terraform plan throws error from kubernetes provider if the cluster was not created yet

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I have a terraform configuration that will create a GKE cluster, node pools and then call kubernetes to setup my app. When I run this configuration on a new project which doesn't have the cluster created yet the kubernetes provider throws below error

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable


Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/cluster-admin-binding": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused


Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/rabbitmq": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
```

If I comment out all kubernetes part, run terraform apply to create the cluster and then uncomment the kubernetes part and try it works fine and creates all kubernetes resource.

I checked the docs for kubernetes provider and it says the cluster should exists already.

[k8s getting started](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/guides/getting-started)

```
There are at least 2 steps involved in scheduling your first container on a Kubernetes cluster. You need the Kubernetes cluster with all its components running somewhere and then schedule the Kubernetes resources, like Pods, Replication Controllers, Services etc.
```

How can I tell terraform to wait for the cluster to created before planning for kubernetes?

My config looks like below
main.tf

```
.
.
.

module "gke" {
  source = "./modules/gke"

  name                     = var.gke_cluster_name
  project_id               = data.google_project.project.project_id
  gke_location             = var.gke_zone
  .
  .
  .
}

data "google_client_config" "provider" {}

provider "kubernetes" {
  version                = "~> 1.13.3"
  alias                  = "my-kuber"
  host                   = "https://${module.gke.endpoint}"
  token                  = data.google_client_config.provider.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.gke.cluster_ca_certificate
  load_config_file       = false
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ns" {
  provider = kubernetes.my-kuber
  depends_on = [module.gke]

  metadata {
    name = var.namespace
  }
}
```

Comment: Post complete examples. You are probably missing one or more `depends_on`.